# webRTC order and signaling server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc, peer

So I am trying to set up a webRTC video connection through a signaling server with `socket.io`. I have gotten past `setLocalDescription` which allows me to get the ice candidates, which I believe from reading is the right way, but how do I add the ice candidates. I see that I have to use something like the following: `myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(RTCIceCandidate);` but do I add this to both my remote and local peer connection? Do i send the `evt.candidates` to my signaling server and add them there? and If so, how? the variable for adding to peer connection isn't global. I've been working on this for a few days now and I think I'm at the point where I just need a guide, something better than the tutorials online, and I've looked at all i can find.

This is the code attached to my html: client.js

```
var socket = io.connect();

var myPeerConnection;
var remotePeerConnection;
var offer;

var PeerConnectionWindow = (window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection 
|| window.webkitRTCPeerConnection || window.msRTCPeerConnection);
var SessionDescription = (window.RTCSessionDescription || window.mozRTCSessionDescription 
|| window.webkitRTCSessionDescription || window.msRTCSessionDescription);


    function hasUserMedia() { 
   //check if the browser supports the WebRTC 
   return !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || 
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia); 
}




if (hasUserMedia()) {

   var configuration = { 
      "iceServers": [{ "url": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" }] 
   }; 

   myPeerConnection = new PeerConnectionWindow(configuration);
   console.log(myPeerConnection);

   remotePeerConnection = new PeerConnectionWindow(configuration);
   console.log(remotePeerConnection);

   myPeerConnection.createOffer(gotDescription, onError);

   myPeerConnection.onicecandidate = function(evt){
      if(event.candidate){
         socket.emit('ice', JSON.stringify({'ice': evt.candidate}));
         remotePeerConnection.addIceCandidate(evt.candidate);
         console.log("connected my to remote");
      }
   };

   remotePeerConnection.onicecandidate = function(evt){
      if(event.candidate){
         socket.emit('ice', JSON.stringify({'ice': evt.candidate}));
         myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(evt.candidate);
         console.log("connected my to remote");
      }
   };

   remotePeerConnection.onaddstream = function (evt) {
      console.log("on added stream");
      var remoteVid = document.getElementById('remote'); 

      remoteVid.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(evt.stream);
   }

   navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia
   || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia; 
   //enabling video and audio channels 
   navigator.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, function (stream) {  
      var video = document.getElementById('local');  
      // //inserting our stream to the video tag     
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      myPeerConnection.addStream(stream); 
   }, onError); 
} else { 
   alert("WebRTC is not supported"); 
}

function gotDescription(desc) {
   offer = desc
   myPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer, myPeerConnLocalDescSet, onError);
   socket.emit('description', JSON.stringify({'sdp': desc}));
}

function onError(err){
   console.log(err);
}

function myPeerConnLocalDescSet(){
   remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer, remotePeerConnRemoteDescSet,onError);
}

function remotePeerConnRemoteDescSet(){
   remotePeerConnection.createAnswer(onAnswerCreated, onError);
}

function onAnswerCreated(description){
   answer = description;
   remotePeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer, remotePeerLocalDescSet,onError);
}

function remotePeerLocalDescSet(){
   myPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer, myPeerRemoteDescSet,onError);
}

function myPeerRemoteDescSet(){
   console.log('did we get it?');
}
```

and this is my signaling server: server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);



app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("in the socket on server");

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('description', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
    socket.on('ice', function(data){
        // Do I attempt to add the candidate here like so?: myPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(data));
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

So it looks like everything flows in terms of order so I updated my code. Now I only need help with how to exchange the SDP information between the two peers. What I have now is them being sent to `Socket.io` to be picked up and applied by both parties...right? Does someone have some example code of how this is done they can show me with an explanation. Please and thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out how to communicate with socket.io through some basic tutorials if anyone was interested but most importantly I discovered that the order for webrtc is super important. After having the right code and calls the peer-to-peer was still not being completed and that's because **ONADDSTREAM HAS TO BE CALLED ON THE REMOTE AND ADDSTREAM ON THE LOCAL BEFORE YOU CREATE THE OFFER**

That's for anyone else who wasted a few hours on such simple ish.

Comment: onaddstream is an event listener, not something you call. But yes, you have to add an event listener in order not to avoid missing out.

Answer (score 0):

First implementation are always tricky, and the ICE candidates interfaces (add and on) are very confusing indeed. You can take a look at that diagram for reference of which event is called when, and what API should be used. You can see that when a candidate is created locally (onIceCandidate event) it needs to be passed to the remote side through signaling, and there added using the addIceCandidate API. Since it s symmetric, onIceCandidate always provides local candidates, and addIceCandidate always takes remote candidate as arguments.

http://www.slideshare.net/alexpiwi5/overviewpeerconnectionlifetime

Comment: I do think I've managed to track down my problem to sending and receiving the SDP offer from both parties. Do i need socket.io or server for that? I'm not sure If from what I'm reading that both ways work or that only one does?

Comment: you use web sockets to exchange offer, answer and candidates between peers. it's an exchange, so it needs to go both ways. offer will go from caller to callee, answer the other way, and candidates will go both ways.